# Problem installing Cucumber in Rubymine 3.1 on Windows OS

Tags: rspec, cucumber, rubymine

I am trying to install cucumber plugin in Rails 3.0 ( RubyMine 3.1), but still not able to install it. I want to install cucumber such that RubyMine 3.1 IDE will have the option of generating cucumber like we have generating scaffold.

Ref:

1. https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails
2. https://github.com/derfred/plugin_with_rspec_generator
3. https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/rails

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you've got the proper gems installed (rails, rspec, cucumber, etc.), you should be able to run the rails generator via RubyMine.

Ctrl+Alt+G should get you the dialog window. After that, just select 'generator' option in the dynamic drop down menu. You'll get a another dialog asking you for the generator options. Type: `cucumber:install`. You should be able to find the `cucumber:feature` option in the generator menu

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried but got the following error -> `const_defined?': wrong constant name Cucumber:installGenerator (NameError). I have installed these gems : rspec,rspec-rails,cucumber,cucumber-rail,webrat.